# How to use a rest api in express

Tags: rest, express

I am new to express and have made a rest API in it. I don't know how to implement a rest API in express.So if I want to implement this API in my other applications I don't know how to do it and if I search the web I only get how to build a rest API. Help would be really appreciated

Comment: Your question says "I am new to Express and have made a rest API in it".  Then, you say "I don't know how to implement a rest API in Express".  I'm confused. Which is it.  Did you make a rest API?  Or you don't know how to make a rest API?  What exactly do you need help with?  If you know what a rest API is, you just create a set of Express request handlers that implement your desired rest API.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am following a tutorial from web dev simplified. so now when I want to use this rest API in the backend of my application I do not know how to use it.

Comment: The question as it's written right now is very hard to answer. It could use a lot more detail, perhaps even some code. Do you know what a HTTP request is and how to make one? If the answer is yes, it's unclear to me exactly what's confusing you/what you are stuck on. What did you try?

Comment: @Evert sorry about the question but i just do not know how to express it. so I have made a rest API that creates and finds users. i have deployed it to heroku and now I want to use it in my other website. how shall I use it?

Comment: Do you know about [The Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)?

Comment: @Evert no. i do not know the fetch api

Comment: Ok, well.. fetch is a HTTP client that runs in a browser. If you have a REST api and you want to call it, you need a HTTP client. If this is completely new to you, start learning there.

Comment: so can i use the fetch api in express backend?

Comment: Get an http request library such as [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) or any of the choices listed [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  Then, use that library to make http requests from your application backend to your rest API server and get the response back.

Comment: Is your question meant to be: "I don't know how to make requests to an API server from an Express server"?

Comment: I would suggest you edit your question to make it a lot clearer what you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get an http request library such as [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) or any of the choices listed [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  Then, use that library to make http requests from your application backend to your rest API server and get the response back.

Example:

```
const got = require('got');

got(someRestURL).json().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```